# Part of requested market data is not subscribed-ib_insync

Tags: interactive-brokers

I have a problem with getting option parameters using the library ib_insync.

```
import time

from ib_insync import *
import pandas as pd
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ibapi.common import TickerId, SetOfFloat, SetOfString, MarketDataTypeEnum

config = ConfigParser()



# TWs 7497, IBGW 4001

def get_chain(ib,ticker, exp_list):
    exps = {}
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['strike', 'kind', 'close', 'last'])
    for i in exp_list:
        ib.sleep()

        cds = ib.reqContractDetails(Option(ticker, i, exchange='SMART'))
        options = [cd.contract for cd in cds]
        tickers = [t for i in range(0, len(options), 100)

                   for t in ib.reqTickers(*options[i:i + 100])]

        for x in tickers:
            df = df.append(
                {'strike': x.contract.strike, 'kind': x.contract.right, 'close': x.close, 'last': x.last, 'bid': x.bid,
                 'ask': x.ask, 'mid': (x.bid + x.ask) / 2, 'volume': x.volume}, ignore_index=True)
            exps[i] = df

    return exps


def get_individual(ib,ticker, exp, strike, kind):

    cds = ib.reqContractDetails(Option(ticker, exp, strike, kind, exchange='SMART'))
    options = [cd.contract for cd in cds]
    tickers = [t for i in range(0, len(options), 100) for t in ib.reqTickers(*options[i:i + 100])]

    con = {'strike': tickers[0].contract.strike, 'kind': tickers[0].contract.right, 'close': tickers[0].close,
           'last': tickers[0].last, 'bid': tickers[0].bid, 'ask': tickers[0].ask, 'volume': tickers[0].volume}
    return con


def main():
    with IB().connect('127.0.0.1', 7497) as ib:
        ib.reqMarketDataType(3)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(get_chain(ib,"AAPL", ["20220211"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output: *"Error 10090, reqId 4: Part of requested market data is not subscribed. Subscription-independent ticks are still active.Delayed market data is available.AAPL NASDAQ.NMS/TOP/ALL"*

My solution was to implement ib.sleep because I thought maybe the calls are overlapping. As you can see the MarketDataType is set to 3.

In the end a table with strikes and all other parameters are NaN. Sometimes the first row gets some values, because of this I think it is some kind of overlapping problem.

[image]

Sorry if my question is to long.